# Removing Event Listeners Inside of a Function

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I've got two vote buttons (yes/no), each with an event listener. If they click no, I want to remove the yes. But that removeEventListener within the voteNo function appears to not be removing the voteYes listener.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

```
document.getElementById("voteButtonYesID").style.display = "inline";
document.getElementById("voteButtonNoID").style.display = "inline";
        // listen for the no click
document.getElementById('voteButtonNoID').addEventListener('click', (e) => voteNo(e, direction),{once: true});

        // listen for the yes click
document.getElementById('voteButtonYesID').addEventListener('click', (e) => voteYes(e, direction),{once: true});


    function voteNo(e, direction) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // clear the voting buttons
        document.getElementById("voteMessageID").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("voteButtonYesID").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("voteButtonNoID").style.display = "none";

        document.getElementById('voteButtonNoID').removeEventListener('click', voteNo);
        document.getElementById('voteButtonYesID').removeEventListener('click', voteYes);
```

**EDIT: I feel like I am almost there.** I'm able to pass the `direction` argument and use `preventDefault(e)` by using a named function. However...

Clicking the No button and the function executes, but it still does not remove the Yes button `event listener`. I have read that I can store the `voteNo` function in a variable so I can call it the same way for the add and remove event listeners, but I don't see how I could then pass my `direction` variable.

```
    function voteNoClickCancel(direction) {
        return function(e){
            e.preventDefault()
            
            document.getElementById('voteButtonYesID').removeEventListener('click', voteYesClickTrigger(direction));

            voteResults('no',direction);
        }
    }
```

```
        // listen for the no click
      document.getElementById('voteButtonNoID').addEventListener('click', voteNoClickCancel(direction),{once: true});

        // listen for the yes click
      document.getElementById('voteButtonYesID').addEventListener('click', voteYesClickTrigger(direction),{once: true});
```

FINAL ANSWER:

I ultimately was not able to bring in the function argument `direction`, handle the  `preventDefault(e)`, and `removeEventHandler`. I'm sure there's a way to do it, but I took out the argument piece by making `direction` a global variable and not trying to pass it into the function.

```
const handleNoCancel = function voteNoClickCancel(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        document.getElementById('voteButtonYesID').removeEventListener('click', handleYesTrigger,{once: true});
        voteResults('no',hikeDirection); //hikeDirection is the new global variable
    }
```

```
document.getElementById('voteButtonNoID').addEventListener('click', handleNoCancel,{once: true});
```

Comment: The argument to `removeEventListener()` has to be the same function that was given to `addEventListener()`. You're using a function name when you remove, but an arrow function when you add, so they don't match.

Comment: `voteNo()` only takes one argument. Why are you calling it with 2 arguments? There's no `direction` parameter.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to simplify my code for posting and removed the direction argument, but I do use it within my function. I use the e argument so I can preventDefault the event, and then direction is passed to a later socket.io call. I've added back in here.

Comment: Then you're not going to be able to use `removeEventListener`. There's no way to remove an anonymous function.

Answer (score 1):

You never assigned `voteNo` as an event listener, you assigned anonymous function `(e) => voteNo(e, direction)`

You would have to declare this function before

Comment: I had tried creating a named function for each event listener, but I was struggling with passing both the `e` argument so I could `preventDefault` and the `direction` argument which I need to carry into the function. That's why I have the arrow functions, but it sounds like I need to create the named functions instead, correct? I wasn't able to do it before but can try to figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: Where does this direction come from?

Comment: They are able to click on north, east, or west. Let's say they click north. These 2 vote buttons come up asking if they are sure they want to go north. If yes, the `direction` variable needs to be passed so a socket emit can tell the other players that this player wants to go north. So it is just a variable based on the direction they clicked.

Comment: Doesn't `once: true` already do what you want?

Comment: Heh, I thought so, too. I think removing the no button event listener within the function is pointless because it's done with the `once: true`. My struggle is that the yes button event listener isn't getting removed once I get into the voteNo function. No button gets cleared, but the Yes button event handler doesn't get removed because it wasn't the listener (and then function) that was clicked. It seems like there's an easy solution to remove that Yes event listener within the voteNo function, I just can't get to it.

Comment: Edited the original post with new, streamlined code that still isn't quite there....